# UIAlertController bug changing tintcolor of other UIImageViews

Tags: ios8, uiimageview, uialertcontroller, tintcolor

I have what I assume is an odd iOS8 bug. Whenever I launch a `UIAlertController`I find that it is changing all of the tint colors of my `UIImageViews` that use the `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` image rendering mode to a dark grey. This happens whether or not I adjust the tint color of the `UIAlertController`. Below find a screenshot (Look at the bubble corners) which were the correct color before the `UIAlertController` was displayed and return to the correct color once it is dismissed.

Anybody know how to prevent this in iOS8?

[image]

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question ended %@",[endDateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:selectedActivity.utc]]]
                                      message:messageText
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
[alertController.view setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:240.0/360 saturation:.03 brightness:.58 alpha:1]];

//...Add some actions and then
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Whenever a modal view is presented the tint color of the views behind it are changed to a gray "dimmed" color to indicate that they are not interactive. You should be able to fix this issue by setting the `tintAdjustmentMode` property of your `UIImageView`s.

See:
[UIKit Framework > UIView Class Reference > Configuring a View's Visual Appearance > tintAdjustmentMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tintAdjustmentMode)